# how to create a "light and dark" functioning button using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to do it by changing my :root variables for the color scheme of the page with a function changeBackgrondColor() and assigning to my fontAwesome moon "button". However, when i click at the moon, the page changes all of the colors for a sec and then comeback to the original form.

```
var r = document.querySelector(':root');
var rootStyles = getComputedStyle(r);
function changeBackgroundColor(){
    r.style.setProperty('--clr-1', 'blue');
    r.style.setProperty('--clr-2', 'blue');
    r.style.setProperty('--clr-3', 'blue');
    r.style.setProperty('--clr-4', 'blue');
}
```

Comment: Can you convert your code into a snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you set class `theme-dark` to `body` element and use CSS veriables for colors:

```css
.theme-dark{
  --body-bg:#333;
  --color:#aaa;
  --input-bg: #555;
}
body{
  background-color: var(--body-bg);
  color: var(--color);
}

input, button{
  color: var(--color);
  background-color: var(--input-bg);
}
```

```html
<input><button onclick="document.body.classList.toggle('theme-dark')">Toggle dark theme</button>
```

Comment: i could use the same variables i declared at :root and assign at this .theme-dark class with different colors then it changes the page color when i click at the button?

Comment: @JoãoMarcelo yes